# Rebooting A Windows Docker Container

Tags: docker

I had to install a Windows feature on my docker windows container and it requires me to reboot the container. Trying to restart with 'shutdown.exe -r' and 'docker restart ' does not do an actual reboot. I can't seem to figure it out. There are a bunch of use cases that require this and I am surprised it is not an easily accessible feature.

I am using the mcr.microsoft.com/windows:10.0.19041.1415 image from Microsoft.